# The normal plane to a path

Tags: differential-geometry, education, vectors

PROBLEM:

Let $\vec x(t)$ be a path with $\vec x'$x $\vec x'' \ne 0$ and suppose that there is a point $\vec x_0$ that lies on every normal plane to $\vec x$. Show that the image of $\vec x$ lies on a sphere (the normal plane at $t=t_0$ is the plane containing $\vec x(t_0)$ and determined by the normal and binormal vectors $\vec N(t_0)$ and $\vec B(t_0)$).

What's the geometric interpretation of this problem? Can someone solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
(\vec x-\vec x_0)^T\vec x'=0
$$
we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}((\vec x-\vec x_0)^T(\vec x-\vec x_0))=2(\vec x-\vec x_0)^T\vec x'=0
$$
therefore:
$$
(\vec x-\vec x_0)^T(\vec x-\vec x_0)=\text{constant}
$$